# How to load file and format it with dict?

Tags: java, templates, tomcat

In Python, I could load a file as a template and replace its formation marks with a dict.

If this was the HTML/the file

```
<html>
  <body>%(MyVar)s</body
</html>
```

I could do this in Python:

```
f = file("myfile.html").read()
d = {"MyVar":"Hi"}
page = f % d
```

Is there something similar to this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a template engine. such as Velocity, Freemarker.